# Catching COM errors with c#

Tags: c#, com, error-handling

i want to ask, how to catch COM asynchroneous error with c#?
Is it possible at all?

My C# program creates DirectShow graph and that graph uses COM dll (ffmpeg.dll). Graph has its own thread, i want to catch error when that thread fails.
All I get now is error message that my app failed in module ffmpeg.dll.

I need to catch that error and restart the application.

Any ideas how to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(OnUnhandledException);
```